# how to replace a value under specific word in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, find, python-requests

I have this code to interpolate between the values and return Z value for specific X and Y. I am trying to open another file (`world.txt`) and paste the value under specific name `Nz`.

The way the file is organised is

```
Nx
5
Ny
0.1
Nz
0.8
```

But what i am getting is `givemeZ(0.5,0.04)` instead of the value `0.78`

Would you please suggest some ideas of how to fix it?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import itertools
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xx= 0.15, 0.3, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55
yy= 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05
zz= 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79

tck = interpolate.bisplrep(xx, yy, zz, s=0)    
def givemeZ(X,Y):
    return interpolate.bisplev(X,Y,tck)
## to replace the value 
with open('world.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()
# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace('Nz', 'givemeZ(0.5,0.01)')
# Write the file out again
with open('world.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```

Comment: Your code yields an error at `tck = interpolate.bisplrep(xx, yy, zz, s=0)`: *TypeError: m >= (kx+1)(ky+1) must hold* - is this example working for you?

Comment: Just wondering about the numbers...`Nx  5`? Is it `0.5` and `Ny` maybe `0.01`. We are talking about interpolation here not extrapolation, right? Moreover, are you generating world.txt youself? If so, I strongly recommend a different structure, e.g.
# Nx Ny Nz\n
0.5 0.01 0.78\n
... \n
or at least
Nx 0.5\n
Ny 0.01\n
Nz 0.78\n
...\n
that would make your life much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yeah. You pass `filedata.replace` the **string literal** `'givemeZ(0.5,0.01)'`. You should pass it the actual value, converted to a string, like

```
filedata = filedata.replace('Nz', str(givemeZ(0.5,0.01)))
```

Depending on the details, you may be able to get away without the `str()` call - I'm not sure if `replace` will smoothly handle non-`str` arguments that can be converted to `str`. Doing the conversion yourself explicitly should work though.

---

To replace the next line, you need some logic that runs in a loop - I don't think you'll be able to do it purely by a `replace`. You could do something like this:

```
new_lines = []
previous_line = ''
with open('world.txt', mode = 'r') as f:
    for current_line in f:
        if previous_line == 'Nz':
            new_lines.append(str(givemeZ(0.5,0.01)))
        else:
            new_lines.append(current_line)
        previous_line = current_line

new_text = '\n'.join(new_lines)
```

You could then write the new text back to `world.txt` - note that the operations you're doing here, even in your original code, do not modify the actual file, just the Python string in memory.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, but the question is how to change the value under Nz not Nz itself???

Comment: @PrincessZena I've added an example of how to do that.

Comment: @PrincessZena Why? The code I provided does exactly the same thing without needing `replace`. To use `replace` you need to care about the value below `Nz`, which in your example, you don't.

Comment: @PrincessZena It doesn't change **what** value? As I said in my answer, if you want to change the file on disk, you need to write over it.

Comment: I am sorry, but it doesnt over write as well, I am trying and the code is running without error but doesnt change anything in the file. You are very good in Python and I am hoping that would you please help me

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as expected, the line

```
filedata = filedata.replace('Nz', 'givemeZ(0.5,0.01)')
```

replaces the string `Nz` with the string `givemeZ(0.5,0.01)`.

You want to replaze `Nz` with the return value of `givemeZ(0.5,0.01)`. Use the following:

```
filedata = filedata.replace('Nz', str(givemeZ(0.5, 0.01)))
```

This takes the return value of `givemeZ()` and converts this value to a string.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, but the question is how to change the value under Nz not Nz itself???

Comment: It is probably better to use a configuration file format like [yaml](https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/#yaml)